# Program seems to skip 'if' statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector

I'm attempting to create a program that will multiply 3 not equal values from vector 1 ('V1'), and write in vector 2 ('V2'). I'm using 3 'for' loops and an integer that counts vector 2's value's number. But program skips the 'if' statement.

```
#include <vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void earase(vector<int> V2, unsigned int z){
    V2.erase(V2.begin() + z);
}

void main(){
unsigned int N;
unsigned int z = 0;
vector<int> V1;
vector<int> V2;
int input;
ifstream file1;
file1.open("input.txt");
file1 >> N;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    file1 >> input;
    V1.push_back(input);
}
file1.close();

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++){
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++){
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < V1.size(); k++){
            V2.push_back(V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k]);
            if (i == j || i == k || j == k || (i == k ) && k==j)
            {
                void earase(vector<int> V2, unsigned int z);
            }
            z++;
        }
    }
}

sort(V2.begin(), V2.end());

ofstream file2;
file2.open("output.txt");
file2 << V2.back();
file2.close();
}
```

Here is the input.txt file

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

After finishing the program sorts the vector 2 and writes the last number in vector 2 in 'output.txt' but it writes values that will come only if multiply the same value from vector 1, 3 times.

I think the problem is in 'if' statement, and 'z' integer, is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Both `i == k` and `j == k` imply `i == k && k == j`, so the latter is redundant in your disjunction.

Comment: If you're trying to call a function called `earase()`, you're not.

Comment: Doing a long time since i did c++, so i dont know if you can pass a vector in parameter with that syntax. BUT, im sure that the syntax for calling `earase` isnt good, you cannot put the type of variable when calling a function.

Comment: You said "not equal values" but seem to have tried (and failed) to get "not equal positions".  Getting not equal positions is much simpler.  But which do you want?

Comment: You might want to consider adding a set of parenthesis to the if. The compiler usually throws a warning at you if you mix `||` and `&&` without parenthesis (Do you mean `A || (B && C)` or `(A || B) && C)`?) I can never remember which has higher precedence. It might not be doing what you want.

Comment: Since `z` will be wrong, the ultimate call to `erase` would be wrong even if the call to `earase` were really a call.  It would be a lot simpler to make the push properly conditional rather than push things you didn't want and try to erase them

Comment: I'm trying to get not equal positions. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: the program seems to work now, I deleted 'i == k && k == j' and 'z', and changed 'erase' with '.pop_back()'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean exactly what I said. I really meant that the current condition implies the condition `i == k || j == k` and that this condition implies the current one (i.e., the two conditions are equivalent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non equal positions is trivial, no test required (assuming you want each combination only once):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++){
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < j; k++){
            V2.push_back(V1[i] * V1[j] * V1[k]); } } }
```

If for some reason, you wanted all each combination multiple times (as if you had gone through all N cubed possibilities skipping only duplicate positions) just go through the above simple way and push each multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The body of your `if` is actually something quite different than you expect:

```
if (i == j || i == k || j == k || (i == k ) && k==j)
{
    void earase(vector<int> V2, unsigned int z); // <<<<<<<
}
```

You're not **calling** `earase`. Instead, you're **declaring** a function called `earase`. If you want to call the function, call it:

```
if (i == j || i == k || j == k || (i == k ) && k==j)
{
    earase(V2, z);
}
```

By the way you could have easily checked that with some debugging output (like `std::cout << "if entered";` after/before `earase`). However, keep in mind that this won't actually change `V2`.